# Set cookie in one domain and access to another domain in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am new in CodeIgniter and as per my requirement, I need a cookie variable which is set on my one domain and get to another domain. I am using below mentioned code:

For Set-Cookie [On One Domain]:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('email', $this->input->post('email'), time()+3600*2);
```

For Get-Cookie [On Another Domain]:

```
$this->input->cookie('email');
```

But somehow not able to get the above cookie "email" value on another domain. Please assist me, if anyone have solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the other domain a sub domain of the first ?

Comment: No, both are different domain not a sub-domain.

Comment: then am afraid its not possible...cookies are specific to a domain(or its sub-domains), other domains won't be able to access this cookie